# existence of limit when both RHL and LHL approachees Positive infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

We know that if $$\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x)=L$$ Then $$\lim_{x \to a}f(x) =L$$ if $L$ is finite

But if $$\lim_{x \to a^+}f(x) \to +\infty$$ and
$$\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) \to +\infty$$

Can we say $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)$$ Does not exists since we cannot compare two infinities.

Comment: What do you mean "we cannot compare two infinities"? The statement $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ is defined in terms of lower bounds of a function.

Comment: what i mean is if $L$ is finite $L-L=0$, but if $L$ is $\infty$, $\infty-\infty $ is indeterminate. Hence can we say Limit DNE?

Comment: No, the limit is equal to infinity. How would subtraction be involved?

Answer (score 1):

Having $$\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)=\infty$$ alone is enough to conclude that the limit does not exist, since otherwise there is a finite $L$ such that $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L,$$ which implies that $$\lim_{x \to a^+} f(x)=L.$$

Comment: Limits of $\pm \infty$ can exist.

Answer (score 1):

In general, we only say a limit 'exists' when it is finite. When we say $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=+\infty$ we mean that

$$(\forall M>0)\,(\exists \delta > 0)\,(\forall x \,\text{ with }\, 0<|x-a|<\delta)\,\, f(x)>M \tag{1}$$

In other words, $f$ becomes arbitrarily large near $a$ — all of $f$. Contrast this with '$f$ attains arbitrarily large value near $a$'.

---

When we say $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=+\infty$ we mean that

$$(\forall M>0)\,(\exists \delta > 0)\,(\forall x \,\text{ with }\, 0<|x-a|<\delta\,\text{ and }\, x>a)\,\, f(x)>M\tag{2}$$

In other words, $f$ becomes arbitrarily large in a right-neighborhood of $a$ — all of $f$, once again.

---

When we say $\lim_{x\to a^-}f(x)=+\infty$ we mean that

$$(\forall M>0)\,(\exists \delta > 0)\,(\forall x \,\text{ with }\, 0<|x-a|<\delta\,\text{ and }\, x<a)\,\, f(x)>M\tag{3}$$

In other words, $f$ becomes arbitrarily large in a left-neighborhood of $a$ — all of $f$, once again.

---

Can you see how statements $(2)$ and $(3)$, combined, imply statement $(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we say $\lim \limits_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$ does not exists since we cannot compare two infinities?

Yes, we can say that it does not exist at a point $a$ because plus and minus infinities are different behaviors (function growing without bound/decreasing without bound). Moreover, limits of functions that end up in plus or minus infinity actually do not exist either. However, we do write that a limit is equal to $\pm\infty$, but that's only done for the purposes of describing the way a function behaves. It's just supposed to be more informative that way, meaning it gives us more information about a function's behavior near a particular point.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that if you only want to deal with finite limits. But there is a sense in which such functions, for example, $$\frac{1}{x^2}$$ at $x=0$ behave regularly (though grow beyond any bound) at such points. In this case we may then say that the function is infinite at $a,$ so e.g., we may say that $1/x^2$ is infinite at $0.$